# .htaccess Force HTTPS and non-www

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I've been looking for a way to force both https and non-www. In one set of code in `.htaccess` without a redirect loop.

For example:

```
example.com = https://example.com
```

Basically, anything the user types in, it goes to `https://example.com`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: hi this code work for me
`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of all combinations for your specific domain and redirect to `https://example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```